# ipaddress of my VM doesn't look correct

Tags: networking, virtualization

I am trying to setup [metasploitable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/) in a Virtualbox VM. My impression is, that once Virtualbox is set up to work in host-only adapter mode, the VMs should follow the networking settings defined in the following screenshot. Let me show how I set this up. I have a metasploitable VM and its displaying 10.0.2.15 for eth0 in the ifconfig output.

[image]

Here is how Virtualbox network setting are configured. I got no entrys at NAT networks.

[image]

Here is the host-only tabs:
[image]

If I edit this, here is what I see under adaptor tab: 
[image]

and here is the dhcp tab.

[image]

Based on these settings, shouldn't my metasploitable machine obtain the ip address 192.168.56.101 (or up)? Is there anything wrong in my configuration?

**UPDATE**
Once I update network setting, enabling Bridged Mode for that VM, I am now getting following ip. This doesn't look correct based on my settings:

[image]

I get following error with dhclient command

[image]

Comment: Is dynamic IP via DHCP activated in the guest machine? Your Virtualbox config seems to be correct.

Comment: where can I do that?

Comment: You have to run dhclient as a superuser.

Comment: this seems like more of a serverfault stackexchange type question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your settings into a "Bridged" adapter. Your IP information is suggesting/showing that you are running the interface in NAT mode. Click on the image, go to settings for that guest. Select network, then adapter, in the drop down box where you assigned the adapter make sure the "Attached to" settings is set to "Bridged Adapter"

[image: Settings for Network Adapter]

Comment: Updated my question with your suggested settings applied. Still get same ip address

Comment: @pauldeter after you change your settings, you may need to either run dhclient eth0 or statically assign it: ifconfig eth0 192.168.56.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 ; route add default 192.168.56.1

Comment: wait a minute, actually restarting the vm bring up a new ip address. I am not sure if its correct one. Let me add that image in my question

Comment: updated my question with the new ip i am getting.

Comment: I re-read and saw the "Virtual Host Only" adapter. I don't ever use them, nor have I configure them however, statically assigning the ethernet address will work, and any network IP addressing you use would be irrelevant to any network as the data/network/packets would never leave that host. Statically assign the address

Comment: Statically assigning address gives "SIOCSIFADDR: Permission denied" error

Comment: Clarification on Bridge Adapter / Bridged networking: This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.

Comment: Means: 192.168.1.5 is an ip assigned by your local dhcp server, propably home router.

Comment: I down voted this answer because you don't want to expose a Metasploitable instance to the outside world which setting `Bridged Apdater` would do. Please see me answer below or a more secure setup.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, to use your virtualbox-host-only-dhcp you have to assign host-only mode in your vm config and obtain a new ip via dhcp, other ways to do this are restarting your network interface or rebooting the machine.

Take a look at the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for more information about networking modes.

Comment: ok thanks, will I be able to access internet from my vm with host only mode?

Comment: No, hence the name "host only". Unless you use another VM as a router on that network.

Comment: Another way to access the internet is using Bridged Mode instead of Host-Only Mode like stated in munkeyotos Answer. Its not really clear what you are trying to achieve because you didnt ask a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this and the way to securely create a VM network is to create a NAT Network and assign that to the VMs. Using Mac OS X and VirtualBox (Version 5.2.24 r128163 (Qt5.6.3)), one can create a `NAT Network` by:

1. Press `⌘,` to open preferences dialog
2. Select the `Network` icon
3. Select "Adds new NAT Network" icon

Then for each VM:

1. Select the VM
2. Press `⌘s` to open its settings dialog
3. Select the `Network` icon
4. On the `Attached To:` drop down, select `NAT Network`

The one you just created should be automatically selected. When you restart each VM they should all be in a network where they can speak to each other and the outside network but not vice-versa. This [table](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#table-networking-modes) expresses that pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this question has been out for a while but I found the required solution.

What is the issue ?

Essentially when creating a VM in VirtualBox it is created in an isolated environment so you need to create a new "NAT network" for the required VMs to be able to communicate with each other under the created network.

This can be done within VirtualBox by doing the following:

1. Open VirtualBox and navigate to 'Tool' --> 'Preferences' --> Network
2. Add a new network using the green button on the top right
3. Edit the network and assign it a new name and IP range if you'd like
4. Go to the VM's and in there settings go to 'Network' --> change it to 'NAT Network' and you should see the name of your new created VM once you selected it.

Hope this helps!